# How can I display a regular image as a rounded one?

Tags: javascript, html

So this is what I want to do :

[image]

I have a regular rectangle image, and I want to be displayed as a rounded image. How can I do this?

[(Image credit)](http://dribbble.com/shots/512079-Profile-Page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I got this right:

- you have a rectangular non-square image, something like this

  [image: width > height]

  *(width > height)* or like this

  [image: height > width]

  *(height > width)*
- and you want to display it in a circle without distorting it,
  probably as much as you can display of it and the central part,
  something like this:

  [image: in a circle]

---

## Solutions:

### 2023 solution

Give the image either a `width` or a `height` an `aspect-ratio` of `1` (square) and set `object-fit: cover` on it.

```css
img {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%
}

img:nth-child(odd) { width: 10em }
img:nth-child(even) { height: 10em }
```

```html
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664985363388-0e4bd2b5cdb6?w=250'>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700587085844-b96c27958df2?w=250'>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1699976971092-7c92ce87965d?w=250'>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1702141258459-6dd8f817e79a?w=250'>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1699031153161-b719847e2607?w=250'>
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1702121269747-fe91af4fa4a8?w=250'>
```

### Original 2012 solutions, preserved for web history reasons, but please don't do this nowadays anymore

*When you know the size of the image* it is really simple: you put it in a wrapper, give a wrapper a `width` and a `height` that are both equal to the minimum between the `width` and the `height` of the image itself. You then give the wrapper `border-radius: 50%;` and `overflow: hidden;`.

Next, you position the image such that the central part is visible.

- if the `width` of the image is greater than its `height` *(landscape
  image)*, then you set its left margin to be `(height-width)/2`
- otherwise, if the `height` of the image id greater than its `width`
  *(portrait image)*, then you set its top margin to be `(width-height)/2`

### [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3884031)

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<a href='#' class='circle-wrap'>
    <img src='image.jpg'>
</a>
```

Relevant **CSS** for *landscape* image (dimensions: `468px` x `159px`):

```
.circle-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 159px; height: 159px; /* height of img */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-wrap img {
    margin: 0 0 0 -154px; /* (height-width)/2 */
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a JavaScript solution (I'm suggesting this because you list [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) among the tags) if *you don't know anything about the orientation (portrait or landscape) of your image or about its dimensions*.

### [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hHnrL)

I've used a few images of different orientations sizes for testing. The **HTML** for one:

```
<a class='circle-wrap' href='#'>
  <img src='image.jpg'>
</a>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.circle-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-wrap img { display: block; }
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var wrps = document.querySelectorAll('.circle-wrap'), 
    toCircle = function(a) {
      var style, w, h, img;
      for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        style = window.getComputedStyle(a[i]);
        w = parseInt(style.width.split('px')[0],10);
        h = parseInt(style.height.split('px')[0],10);
        /* part that makes the wrapper circular */
        a[i].style.width = a[i].style.height = Math.min(w,h)+'px';
        /* part that takes care of centering imgs */
        img = a[i].querySelector('img');
        if(w > h)
          img.style.marginLeft = ((h - w)/2) + 'px';
        else if(w < h)
          img.style.marginTop = ((w - h)/2) + 'px';
      }
    };

toCircle(wrps);
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
img { border-radius:50%; }
```

Note that the image must have equal width and height for this to work. If the image doesn't, you can set the width and height with CSS as well.

```
img { border-radius:50%; width:200px; height:200px; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/nE7BA/)

Comment: Its nice but if the image is large then it become oval.

Comment: Give it an equal width and height.

Comment: that will mess up the aspect ratio

Comment: If you pay close attention to the image you posted, it's a square image turned into a circle with this same technique. It's either a square that turns into a perfect circle or a rectangle that becomes oval with this.

Comment: You'll have to cut out part of the image (with either JS or setting it as a background with CSS or canvas) if you want to keep aspect ratio while having a perfect circle, but if you don't give any more details I can't really improve my answer.

Comment: @Jimmy "Turn a rectangle into a circle while keeping the aspect ratio" doesn't seem to be allowed by physic rules, now if you opt to cut out a part of the image or to leave blank space inside the circle, I could try to update my answer (even though most likely none of these would look too appealing).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is CSS to do this:

```
<img class='circle' src='/my/img/path/img.jpg' />

<style type="text/css">
    img.circle {
        -ie-border-radius: 50%;    /* IE */
        -khtml-border-radius: 50%; /* KHTML */
        -o-border-radius: 50%;     /* Opera */
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;   /* Mozilla / FF */
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;/* Chrome / Safari */
        border-radius: 50%;        /* CSS Compliant */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a white square image with a transparent circle in the middle and overlay on the image.